# How to remove dashes in UUID with nodejs?

Tags: node.js, uuid

I'm trying to remove the dashes in the UUID by using the replace function on NodeJS but unsuccessful as it always returns with dashes.

```
const { v4: uuidv4 } = require('uuid');

const uuid = uuidv4().toString()

console.log(uuid.replace("-",""))
```

The code above is what I'm trying to do to remove the dashes. Thanks

Comment: Use a global replacement: `uuid.replace(/-/g, "")`

Comment: If you're on Node 15+, you can use `replaceAll("-", "")` instead.

Comment: thanks guys. it works on both solutions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

function replace only try 1 times

you can replace all '-' use RegExp like this:

```
uuid.replace(/-/gi, '');
```